# UIToolBar bar button items NOT showing with Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I am making an app without using Interface Builder, so I'm creating everything by code.

I have a view controller that is embedded in a navigation controller. I know navigation controllers have a toolbar property, and all I need to do is set the boolean to false to unhide it. My code looks like this (it is a function called in viewDidLoad):

```
func setUpToolBar(){
    navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false
    navigationController?.toolbar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    navigationController?.toolbar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    toolItems.append(addImageButton)
    toolItems.append(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil))
    toolItems.append(exportImageButton)
    toolItems.append(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil))
    toolItems.append(deleteImageButton)

    navigationController?.toolbar.setItems(toolItems, animated: false)

}
```

Here is where and how I am declaring these properties for my view controller:

```
private var addImageButton : UIBarButtonItem = {
    let button = UIFactory.createBarButtonItem(nil, imageNamed: "plus button", style: .Plain, target: ImagesCollectionViewController.self, selector: #selector(ImagesCollectionViewController.addImage))
    return button
}()
private var exportImageButton : UIBarButtonItem = {
    let button = UIFactory.createBarButtonItem(nil, imageNamed: "export button", style: .Plain, target: ImagesCollectionViewController.self, selector: #selector(ImagesCollectionViewController.exportImagePressed))
    return button
}()
private var deleteImageButton : UIBarButtonItem = {
    let button = UIFactory.createBarButtonItem(nil, imageNamed: "trash button", style: .Plain, target: ImagesCollectionViewController.self, selector: #selector(ImagesCollectionViewController.deleteImagePressed))
    return button
}()

private var toolItems : [UIBarButtonItem] = []
```

Here is the function for my UIFactory class which simply handles the hassle of creating these UI items outside of the view controller

```
class func createBarButtonItem(title: String?, imageNamed : String?, style : UIBarButtonItemStyle?, target : AnyObject?, selector : Selector?) -> UIBarButtonItem{
    let button = UIBarButtonItem()
    if let theTitle = title {
        button.title = theTitle
    }
    if let theImageName = imageNamed {
        button.image = UIImage(named: theImageName)
    }
    if let theStyle = style{
        button.style = theStyle
    }
    if let theTarget = target {
        button.target = theTarget
    }
    if let theSelector = selector {
        button.action = theSelector
    }
    return button
}
```

And, after running this code in the simulator, this is what I see (no toolbar items! Also, notice I have a bar button item in that navigation bar, which I added in code just fine)

[image: screenshot]

Please, someone help me. I am stuck on such a nonsensical step and I can't proceed with my app without this.

Comment: Where are you calling setupToolbar?

Comment: Called in ViewDidLoad

Comment: That may be too early. If `navigationController?` is still nil, then your code would not have any effect. Is it nil? If so, try moving the call to `setupToolbar` to `viewWillAppear` or someplace similar.

Comment: Unbelievable. It worked. Thanks!

Comment: Does toolItems need to be initialized?

Answer (score 8):

Just remove

```
navigationController?.toolbar.setItems(toolItems, animated: false)
```

And put this line of code

```
self.toolbarItems = [toolItems]
```

Comment: This works for me, wondering why "self.navigationController?.toolbar.items = items" and "self.navigationController?.setToolbarItems(items, animated: false)" doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

I changed

> navigationController!.toolbar.setItems(toolItems, animated: true)

to

> toolbarItems = toolItems

and worked for me.